# Passing value from DataGridView cell to textbox in VB.NET

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I need to pass value from `DataGridView` cell to textbox in VB.NET.
I tried but it's not working.

```vb
Private Sub Cmdsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cmdsave.Click
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DGVorders.SelectedRows
        Me.TextBox2.Text = rw.Cells(7).Value.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what results are you seeing?  Empty textbox? An error?  One thing to note: you assign `TextBox2.Text` for each selected row - meaning it will only have the `rw.Cells(7).Value` of the *last* selected row.